# Impala/Hive to get list of tables along with its size

Tags: sql, oracle, hadoop, hive, impala

I have used a query in **Oracle DB** to produce the list of tables in a database along with its owner and respective table size. Here is the sample query i have shared.

```
select owner, table_name, round((num_rows*avg_row_len)/(1024*1024)) MB 
from all_tables 
where owner not like 'SYS%'  -- Exclude system tables.
and num_rows > 0  -- Ignore empty Tables.
order by MB desc -- Biggest first.
```

I want the similar output from Impala/Hive.

Note: I tried `show table stats <table_name>` which will show the stats for individual table. But i want to get all the table stats in one go. Can someone help me in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Hive

**CLI**

```
show table extended like '.*'
```

---

```
tableName:t100k
owner:cloudera
location:file:/home/cloudera/local/t100k
inputformat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
outputformat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
columns:struct columns { i32 i}
partitioned:false
partitionColumns:
totalNumberFiles:1
totalFileSize:588895
maxFileSize:588895
minFileSize:588895
lastAccessTime:0
lastUpdateTime:1492675975000

tableName:t10k
owner:cloudera
location:file:/home/cloudera/local/t10k
inputformat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
outputformat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
columns:struct columns { i32 i}
partitioned:false
partitionColumns:
totalNumberFiles:1
totalFileSize:48894
maxFileSize:48894
minFileSize:48894
lastAccessTime:0
lastUpdateTime:1492675978000

tableName:t1k
owner:cloudera
location:file:/home/cloudera/local/t1k
inputformat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
outputformat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
columns:struct columns { i32 i}
partitioned:false
partitionColumns:
totalNumberFiles:1
totalFileSize:3893
maxFileSize:3893
minFileSize:3893
lastAccessTime:0
lastUpdateTime:1492675983000

tableName:t1m
owner:cloudera
location:file:/home/cloudera/local/t1m
inputformat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
outputformat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
columns:struct columns { i32 i}
partitioned:false
partitionColumns:
totalNumberFiles:1
totalFileSize:6888896
maxFileSize:6888896
minFileSize:6888896
lastAccessTime:0
lastUpdateTime:1492675968000
```

**Metastore (e.g. MySql)**

```
select    d.name                                                                                         as db_name
         ,t.tbl_name                                                                                     as tbl_name
         ,from_unixtime(min(t.create_time))                                                              as create_time
         ,min(t.owner)                                                                                   as owner
         ,min(case when tp.param_key = 'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'  then tp.param_value                 end) as COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE
         ,min(case when tp.param_key = 'last_modified_by'       then tp.param_value                 end) as last_modified_by
         ,min(case when tp.param_key = 'last_modified_time'     then from_unixtime(tp.param_value)  end) as last_modified_time  
         ,min(case when tp.param_key = 'numFiles'               then tp.param_value                 end) as numFiles
         ,min(case when tp.param_key = 'numRows'                then tp.param_value                 end) as numRows
         ,min(case when tp.param_key = 'rawDataSize'            then tp.param_value                 end) as rawDataSize
         ,min(case when tp.param_key = 'totalSize'              then tp.param_value                 end) as totalSize
         ,min(case when tp.param_key = 'transient_lastDdlTime'  then from_unixtime(tp.param_value)  end) as transient_lastDdlTime
         
from            metastore.DBS           as d
          join  metastore.TBLS          as t
          on    t.db_id = d.db_id
          join  metastore.TABLE_PARAMS  as tp
          on    tp.tbl_id = t.tbl_id
          
group by  d.name
         ,t.tbl_name
         
order by  d.name
         ,t.tbl_name
```

---

```
+---------+----------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+------------------+---------------------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| db_name | tbl_name |     create_time     |  owner   | COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE | last_modified_by | last_modified_time  | numFiles | numRows | rawDataSize | totalSize | transient_lastDdlTime |
+---------+----------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+------------------+---------------------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| local   | t100k    | 2017-04-19 23:25:20 | cloudera | true                  | cloudera         | 2017-04-19 23:27:28 |        1 |  100000 |      488895 |    588895 | 2017-04-20 01:12:55   |
| local   | t10k     | 2017-04-19 23:25:26 | cloudera | true                  | cloudera         | 2017-04-19 23:27:26 |        1 |   10000 |       38894 |     48894 | 2017-04-20 01:12:58   |
| local   | t1k      | 2017-04-19 23:25:30 | cloudera | true                  | cloudera         | 2017-04-19 23:27:22 |        1 |    1000 |        2893 |      3893 | 2017-04-20 01:13:03   |
| local   | t1m      | 2017-04-19 23:20:59 | cloudera | true                  | cloudera         | 2017-04-19 23:27:30 |        1 | 1000000 |     5888896 |   6888896 | 2017-04-20 01:12:48   |
+---------+----------+---------------------+----------+-----------------------+------------------+---------------------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```